# Why does an infinite sequence of independent random variables exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

My measure theory lecturer gave a long proof due to Rademacher that an infinite sequence of  iid rvs exists (by construction). I am looking for someone to explain the significance of this and why just saying "consider an infinite sequence of coin tosses heads = 1 tails = 0" doesn't work. (in full rigour and generality of measure theory)

Comment: Well, how do you *define* an infinite sequence of coin tosses? What is the universe? What is the $\sigma$-algebra? What is the probability measure?

Comment: The Rademacher functions is a formal model of what you stated informally. My understanding is that prior to these functions, there was a theory with no concrete example (My recollection from reading an excellent monograph by Marc Kac).

Comment: @Mindlack So what if we just said the probability space was $2^\mathbb{N}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra was generated by the subsets $A_i=\{f\in 2^\mathbb{N}\mid f(i)=0\}$ for $i\in\mathbb N$ and define measure on each $A_i$ to be $1/2$ and ... <what is left to be done here>? I guess the essence of the question is either: "What **is** left to be done here"? Or - "Why does it not work?"

Comment: @Mindlack The sample space is just a collection of outcomes of the form "Coin $i$ was heads(tails)". The sigma algebra $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of subsets which specify the outcome of every coin. For the measure, first consider the sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$, the power set algebra, which is generated by taking all events containing finitely many outcomes and assign probabilities in the way you'd expect then apply catheodory extension theorem to get a measure of $\mathcal{E}$

Comment: @Stinking Bishop: what’s left is that you haven’t defined an actual probability measure! You defined the probability only on a “generating set”, but you need to extend it to the $\sigma$-algebra!

Comment: @janes: I don’t understand what you mean by “events which specify the outcome of each coin” or “all events having finitely many outcomes”… but the idea is correct: you define a “pre-measure” on the algebra of sets made with the events involving finitely many coins and then apply Carathéodory to the $\sigma$-algebra it generates.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for pushing me to define everything explictly, I feel like I understand it much better now